# 0 active connection to bitcoin network (testnet)

Tags: synchronization, testnet, bitcoin-qt-setup

I am working with the `testnet`. I downloaded the `bitcoin-core` application on Linux and I am running the version `Bitcoin Core version v0.12.1.0-g9779e1e (64-bit)` I was able to download the bitcoin block, recently its no longer syncing with the bitcoin network. Its showing `3 days behind` and `0 active connection to the bitcoin network`. How can I fix the issue. I want to connect to the `testnet`. I tried to change the network settings in the application. Still its not working.

Comment: I think that may be the same issue as you are asking about in [your other question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/43865/5406).

Comment: @Murch May be there is some issue when I updated to the latest version (`0.12.0`). I deleted the block chain for version `0.12.0` and download the full block chain again for `0.12.1`.

Comment: You probably wouldn't even have to have deleted the chain, just updating the version would probably have allowed your Bitcoin Core to reorganize. Anyway, did that solve your problem?

Comment: @Murch Yes working now. I found a solution from an another forum [link](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1451591.msg14670180#msg14670180)

Comment: Please add your own answer to preserve the information for the next person that finds your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
addnode 185.28.76.179:18333
```

This "well connected testnet node" was suggested to me [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1451591.msg14670180#msg14670180).

Comment: @Murch I have done it.